# How do I deserialized json response in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to deserialized the following json response in c#.

Response:

> {
>       "status": true,
>       "message": "success",
>       "data": [
>           {
>               "message": "MSISDN: 01120511377\nLine Status: ACTIVE\nPlan: B149\n\nBlack Counter: 45 GB 643m, 900sms\nLyt:
>   158\n\nAdditional Usage: RM80.00\n"
>           },
>           {
>               "message": "\nCURRENT CHARGES\nMonthly Charges : RM149.00\nAdditional Usage : RM80.00\n\nTotal Amount Due: RM-158.00"
>           }
>       ] }

I managed to get `status` and `message`, but unable to get the `data` array.

These are my classes:

```
[DataContract]
public class RecMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public string status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string message { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public message data { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class message
{
    [DataMember]
    public string messages { get; set; }
}
```

However, `data`->`messages` is always `null`

UPDATE: SOLVED!!

The classes supposed be like this:

[DataContract]

```
public class RecMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public string status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string message { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public messages[] data { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class messages
{
    [DataMember]
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: try [DataMember]
    public List<message> data { get; set; } as its a collection of messages.

Comment: You have a typo in the message class as the property is also named `message` while you have it as `messages` so it wont map. Also data is a message array `message[]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes should look something like this:

```
public class RecMessage
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<MessageContent> Data { get; set; }
}

public class MessageContent
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And, using [JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to deserialise:

```
var json = "{...}";
var recMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecMessage>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

First change this:

Before:
`public message data { get; set; }`

After:
`public List<message> data { get; set; }`

Here are c# functions I use to serialize/deserialize. It requires Json.net.

```
public static string ToJSON(this Object obj)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
}

public static T FromJSON<T>(string jsonData)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonData);
}
```

You would use it like this:

`RecMessage myMessage = FromJson<RecMessage>(jsonString)`